# 1955 Chrysler No Crank No start

Tags: electrical, chrysler, no-crank-no-start

Hello everyone I have a 1955 Chrysler Windsor which does not run, the lights and horn work but when I crank the key the starter does NOT turn over but the lights do dim. I've replaced all the fuses cleaned the battery terminals etc... I've connected the starter cable to the battery and it did turn over so the starter should be fine. Any ideas of why it doesn't start?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you turn the engine over by hand?

Comment: Yes it is Not Seized

Answer (score 1):

The starter solenoid should engage/push the starter gear into the flywheel , apparently it is not working. When you remove the solenoid , also cleanup/sand the large copper washer that makes contact between the battery cable and starter motor; it will be in rough condition at this age. For what it is worth ; the only ignition coil that ever failed for me was on a 1959 Chrysler . They were pretty cheap , I carried a spare after that - it is  still in the garage.

Comment: Yah, I misread it the first time ... it's most likely the solenoid.